# ng build not working while building Angular5 project with ANT build

Tags: ant, angular5, integration

I have a java application which is running on localhost:9080 and another angular5 project (angularWeb) inside WebContent folder of the same project which runs on different port localhost:4200

As per the requirement I need to integrate both projects to run on same server on localhost:9080 and both (java and angular projects) need to be at the same location which is why i have the angular project in web content folder.

Please help me understand what is missing.

First: I have created a proxy.conf.json file in angular project to target localhost:9080.

Second: I have changed package.json to start the angular application via proxy file as 
"start": "ng serve --proxy-conf proxy.conf.json",

Third: I added some targets in build.xml file

```
...
...
<property name="project.angularWebPath" location="${project.webContentPathh}/angularweb" />
<target name="mkfolders">
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/js" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/css" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/img" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/lib" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/partials" />
</target>
<target name="mkfiles">
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/app.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/controller.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/directives.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/filters.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/services.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/index.html" />
</target>
<target name="ngBuild">
    <echo>Building Angular Project</echo>
    <exec executable="${project.angularWebPath}/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="build" />
        <arg value="--prod" />
        <arg value="--bh" />
    </exec>
    <echo>Built Angular Project</echo>
</target>
<target name="angularBuild">
    <antcall target="mkfolders" />
    <antcall target="mkfiles" />
    <!--<antcall target="npmInstall" />-->
    <antcall target="ngBuild" />
</target>
...
...
```

Now When I run the angularBuild in ANT, it gives the following error

```
Buildfile: D:\devops\repository\komponente_server\RechercheEAR\build.xml
  [clover-env] Loading clover.xml: jar:file:/D:/devops/repository/komponente_server/Shared/testlib/clover.jar!/clover.xml

angularBuild:
  [clover-env] Loading clover.xml: jar:file:/D:/devops/repository/komponente_server/Shared/testlib/clover.jar!/clover.xml

mkfolders:
  [clover-env] Loading clover.xml: jar:file:/D:/devops/repository/komponente_server/Shared/testlib/clover.jar!/clover.xml

mkfiles:
  [clover-env] Loading clover.xml: jar:file:/D:/devops/repository/komponente_server/Shared/testlib/clover.jar!/clover.xml

ngBuild:
        [echo] Building Angular Project

BUILD FAILED
D:\devops\repository\komponente_server\RechercheEAR\build.xml:71: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\devops\repository\komponente_server\RechercheEAR\build.xml:60: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\devops\repository\komponente_server\Recherche\WebContent\angularweb\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.cmd" (in directory "D:\devops\repository\komponente_server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Total time: 6 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Ant's `exec` task has issues launching files directly in Windows. Try setting the `executable` attribute to just `cmd` itself and passing the file as an argument. The official documentation page goes into more detail on why this is the case: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Also, it's generally a good idea to structure your build through target dependencies rather than using a sequential list of `antcall` tasks.

```
<property name="project.angularWebPath" location="${project.webContentPathh}/angularweb" />

<target name="mkfolders">
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/js" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/css" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/img" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/lib" />
    <mkdir dir="${project.webContentPath}/partials" />
</target>

<target name="mkfiles" depends="mkfolders">
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/app.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/controller.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/directives.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/filters.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/js/services.js" />
    <touch file="${project.webContentPath}/index.html" />
</target>

<target name="ngBuild" depends="mkfiles,mkfolders">
    <echo message="Building Angular Project" />
    <exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="/C" />
        <arg value="${project.angularWebPath}/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.cmd" />
        <arg value="build" />
        <arg value="--prod" />
        <arg value="--bh" />
    </exec>
    <echo message="Built Angular Project" />
</target>

<target name="angularBuild" depends="mkfiles,mkfolders,ngBuild" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this did not work. I did some more research and fixed it.